# Mod_rewrite: Redirect to url in query string

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, redirect

Apache server receives request in following format

```
http://192.168.110.65/?http%3A%2F%2Fdev.virtualearth.net
```

How do I have Apache generate a redirect to the query string using mod_rewrite

```
http%3A%2F%2Fdev.virtualearth.net
```

This is my mod_rewrite

```
<IfModule rewrite_module>
RewriteEngine On
ErrorLog "logs/rewrite.log"
LogLevel trace8
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} http
RewriteRule "/" %{QUERY_STRING} [R,END,NE,QSD] 
</IfModule>
```

This is in the logs:

> Cannot map GET /http%3A%2F%2Fdev.virtualearth.net%2FREST%2Fv1%2FImagery%2FMetadata%2FAerialWithLabels%3Fincl%3DImageryProviders%26key%3DArqI7N2ea0D8oysu209dksva2GSUXRIz1fJZigqHRuHNQMhGHvVZwxg76pSlwBFi%26jsonp%3DloadJsonp758595 HTTP/1.1 to file
>
> auth phase 'translate' gave status 403: /http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Imagery/Metadata/AerialWithLabels?incl=ImageryProviders&key=ArqI7N2ea0D8oysu209dksva2GSUXRIz1fJZigqHRuHNQMhGHvVZwxg76pSlwBFi&jsonp=loadJsonp758595

The problem is instead of redirecting to the url in query string, it prepends  current host to the URL (http://xx.xx.xx.xx/URL) and redirect, hence I get a 403. I need to find a way such that in redirection current host is not prepended.

Comment: I'm sure that if you browsed the [tag:mod-rewrite] you would find an answer or something that will help you out. In the meantime, what have you tried and what happened.

Comment: @lain I have updated the post with mod_rewrite i am using and logs output.

Comment: Unfortunately, if the URL in the query string is fully URL encoded like this then I don't think it's possible to do this with mod_rewrite alone. Also note that a script of this nature, allowing arbitrary target URLs, is open to abuse. See also my answer to this related question: http://serverfault.com/questions/793230/htaccess-redirect-to-url-from-query-string

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same thing with Proxy Pass. Try below solution

Open the httpd.conf located in the \conf directory.
Look for the following `LoadModule` directives and uncomment them by removing the # at the beginning of the line.

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
```

At the bottom of the httpd.conf add the following lines to enable the re-rounting.

```
ProxyPass /images http://localhost:8080/images
ProxyPassreverse / http://localhost:8080/
```