# htaccess - redirect to URL from query string

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I have the following URL:

```
example.com/?redirect=some-url-encoded
```

I need to redirect it to the URL specified in the query string (`redirect` parameter).

I have tried:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} redirect=(.+)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1 [R=302,L,QSA]
```

But I got redirected to the URL:

```
example.com/some-url-encoded?redirect=some-url-decoded
```

So:

1. my URL is not decoded
2. old query string is applied.
3. URL is started from example.com

How to handle it properly?

Comment: What _exactly_ is a typical value for the `redirect` URL param?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. my URL is not decoded

The `QUERY_STRING` server variable is not URL decoded, and mod_rewrite will also URL encode the substitution, so you are likely ending up with a doubly encoded URL? You probably need the `NE` (`NOESCAPE`) flag.

However, if colons and slashes (as in `http://`) are URL encoded (ie. `http:%3A%2F%2F`) in the query string parameter then these will be passed through to the substitution already encoded, negating their normal meaning in a URL. Whilst most URL encoding functions will encode these characters, they don't strictly need to be encoded in the URL parameter value (although this can depend on your server config - if you are changing what the server considers URL delimiters - but this is rare). So, encode all other characters, except `:` and `/` in the URL param value. For example, instead of:

```
example.com/?redirect=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.pl%2F
```

Leave the `:` (colon) and `/` (slash) chars unencoded:

```
example.com/?redirect=https://www.google.pl/
```

An alternative, instead of using a URL parameter is to use additional `PATH_INFO` at the end of the URL, since this should be automatically URL decoded. However, this depends on the `AcceptPathInfo` directive and you will also need to enable `AllowEncodedSlashes` (in the server config), but this comes with its own security concerns. See the Apache docs: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowencodedslashes

> 2. old query string is applied.

You are explicitly telling mod_rewrite to apply the original query string with the `QSA` (Query String Append) flag. But it will do this by default anyway. You need to explicity remove it with either the `QSD` (Query String Discard) flag on Apache 2.4+, or append a `?` to the `RewriteRule` substitution.

> 3. URL is started from `example.com`

You need to include an absolute URL (ie. complete with scheme `http://`) in the URL param (or explicitly hard code this in the substitution?). Note that if the colon and/or slashes in `http://` are URL encoded then Apache will not see this as an absolute URL and it will be treated as relative (to the current directory) to which Apache will prefix the directory-prefix and then try to make it absolute (because of the `R` flag - an *external* redirect) by prefixing the protocol and current domain ie. `http://example.com`. Not only does this wholly corrupt the redirect, it will also expose your internal directory structure.

Bringing this all together, try the following:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} redirect=(.+)
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=302,L,NE]
```

This is assuming that the protocol/scheme **is** passed in the query string parameter. eg. `http://example.com/?redirect=http://www.google.pl/`

A parenthesized subpattern in the `RewriteRule` pattern (ie. `(.*)`) would seem to be unnecessary here.

### A word on Security

Note that allowing *any* absolute URL to be used as the target in a simple redirect script like this is a security risk. If hackers were to discover this then it's likely to be abused and used as part of a redirect chain directing users to download malicious software and the like.

See also:
https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/99749/301-redirect-script-being-abused-for-what-purpose

Comment: Hmm thanks for clarification. What if url is already absolute? The value of `redirect` param can be any, aboslute url (like http://www.google.pl, including https).
Maybe other (and simplier) way is to create a php script f.e. that will handle redirection?

Comment: I've updated my answer, assuming the URL is absolute (with protocol). A notable problem is if the colons and slashes in `https://` are also URL encoded - they probably don't need to be (I've covered this in my answer). Yes, I think handling this in a server-side script, rather than by Apache, would be better and safer.

Answer (score 0):

You're going about the wrong way. Use RewriteCond/RewriteRule to rewrite the path (with QSA to keep the query string) to a script (PHP or some CGI, whatever you like), and then have that script embody the logic and correctness constraints to get the redirect you like.

This also provides useful enabling functionality. Some ideas:

- Case-insensitivity, sepeartor-insentivity (this-thing versus thisthing versus...)
- Feed such redirects from a database

  - which could then have a frontend for trusted web-maintainers to add links and allow for some sort of lifecycle maintenance.
- You might even do things like using edit-distance to help determine what document was wanted (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)